# Google Streetview or Bing streetside URL's using Latitude and Longitude

Tags: c#, google-maps, bing-maps, latitude-longitude, google-street-view

I have latitude and longitude co-ordinates and have been trying to open either Google streetview or Bing streetside in a web browser instance.

I have managed to do this using Google street view url below, however I have found that if the coordinates are not exactly on a road it does not work. Instead, you get a map of the whole world.

```
string.Format(
    "http://maps.google.com/?cbll={0},{1}&cbp=12,0,0,0,5&layer=c",
    this.Location.Latitude,
    this.Location.Longitude)
```

The co-ordinates I want to use are in London so it's pretty much all mapped. I'd like to get the nearest street location to appear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I've done in the past is something like this.  I check the StreetViewService has a 'Panorama' within 50 metres of the given location.  Here's some full sample JS code which should work as is.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Streetview</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
html { height: 100% }
body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
#streetView { height: 100%; width: 100%; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function createStreetMap(strMapCanvasID, intLat, intLong)
    {
        //create a google latLng object
        var streetViewLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(intLat,intLong);
        var panorama;

        //once the document is loaded, see if google has a streetview image within 50 meters of the given location, and load that panorama
        var sv = new google.maps.StreetViewService();

        sv.getPanoramaByLocation(streetViewLocation, 50, function(data, status) {
            if (status == 'OK') {
                //google has a streetview image for this location, so attach it to the streetview div
                var panoramaOptions = {
                    pano: data.location.pano,
                    addressControl: false,
                    navigationControl: true,
                    navigationControlOptions: {
                        style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
                    }
                }; 
                var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById(strMapCanvasID), panoramaOptions);
            }
            else{
                //no google streetview image for this location, so hide the streetview div
                $('#' + strMapCanvasID).parent().hide();
            }
        });

        return panorama;
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var myPano = createStreetMap('streetView', 51.513016, -0.144424);
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div>
    <h2>Street View</h2>
    <div id="streetView"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And then I only call this function once the DOM has loaded (otherwise I found errors if trying to do it too soon from within an `initialize` function).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myPano = createStreetMap('streetView', someLatitude, someLongitude);
});
```

I believe in C# instead of using the call to `createStreetMap` from within `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` you would use the [WebBrowser.InvokeScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc491132.aspx) method and do something like this:

```
object[] args = {"streetView",51.513016,-0.144424};
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("createStreetMap",args);
```

See also: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/60924/Using-WebBrowser-Document-InvokeScript-to-mess-aro

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but this looks like it's entirely in JavaScript. The last time I looked Google doesn't have a .NET API.

Comment: And now your edit just added JQuery on top of it, how is this at all helpful to someone attempting this inside of a C#.Net application?

Comment: One of your earlier comments mentioned "the ability to call JavaScript from a C# WebBrowser instance"

Comment: Yes, that would be my answer. But that ability is limited to functionality already existing on the web page. It's extremely difficult to inject new functions without A) causing an exception to occur because of cross domain function calls B) for someone with little to no prior knowledge of JavaScript to just jump right in with JQuery without first learning basics of JavaScript and C) Know how to even put an entire new function from C# into JavaScript.

Comment: Your answer does not at all address the fact that the user is not doing this from a web page, but .Net, and is therefore incomplete. You're just providing a more specific example of exactly what I said to do in my answer. Yes, your answer is correct if this question was about web development, but it's not.

Comment: The way I see it is, your answer basically says "use the Javascript API" but gives no specifics about how to then do a StreetView.  Mine is an extension to yours, in that it gives (most of) the JS code that would then be required.

Comment: I provided links to both MSDN and the Google API main page, as well as a link to W3Schools in a comment to the OP. Those pages provide far more information than I could ever fit into a single answer. My goal was for the OP to see that using the API is an all around better choice for working with Google Maps. Because the question asked wasn't about providing specific examples of how to achieve the functionality through JavaScript, I feel that providing links to sites with tutorials and examples was a better choice.

Comment: This looks interesting. How can I squirt this into the WebBrowser control and how do I execute it. I did learn JavaScript once, I have since forgotten it and now coming back to it is like fighting a dinosaur with a blade of grass.

Comment: I think using something like `object[] args = {"streetView", 1.234, 55.000};
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("createStreetMap",args);` I'll try and update my answer later with a fuller code example

Comment: Answer updated - I'm good on the JS side of things, but defer to anyone else on the C# syntax for the  WebBrowser.InvokeScript stuff

Comment: @duncan See that's much better. That's all I was driving at. I can get behind this answer now. And yes, in most cases, that would be the correct way to execute the JavaScript on the C# end of things.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use something like:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=300x300&format=png&fov=90&location={0},{1}&sensor=false
```

Comment: I'm more interested in opening a google maps page so the user can pan around and browse.

Answer (score 1):

I used to do a lot of Google maps stuff through URL manipulation. That is until I discovered the ability to call JavaScript from a C# `WebBrowser` instance. I typically use the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/) along with the `WebBrowser`'s [InvokeScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc491132.aspx) method to call what I need. I've found it's much more versatile, although it can sometimes be a pain.

Edit: Sorry I realize that isn't necessarily a DIRECT answer to your question but I've discovered that for anything other than the most basic map manipulation, the API and JavaScript provide much better functionality.

Comment: Thats interesting. I'm actually coding from a Windows Store app and am launching a URL to open the web browser. I could integrate the web browser control directly into my page but JavaScript is a pretty scary place for me, is there any good guides on how I can achieve my goal.

Comment: @user1212017 JavaScript really isn't that bad once you learn the basics. And in this case you don't really need to write much JavaScript (you will have to do some with the API), the part that gets tricky is avoiding cross domain calls. If you haven't worked with HTML / JavaScript before, the best place to start would be learning the basics of both OR simply using the built in JavaScript functions on the actual Google Maps page. Using the built in ones doesn't require writing any JavaScript but I don't think they're documented anywhere, I got them through Chrome's JavaScript console.

Comment: @user1212017 http://www.w3schools.com/ was my best friend when learning JavaScript and HTML. They have a lot of really useful tutorials.